# How to calculate the bias when using $\bar{y}^{3}$ as an estimator for $\mu^{3}$?

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

How do I get the following bias when using $\bar{y}^{3}$ as an estimator for $\mu^{3}$ where $y$ is iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$:
$$
\frac{3 \mu \sigma^{2}}{N}+\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[(y-\mu)^{3}\right]}{N^{2}}
$$

I tried the following:

Given that
$$
(\bar{y}- \mu)^{3} = \bar{y}^{3} - 3\bar{y}^{2}\mu + 3\bar{y}\mu^{2} - \mu^{3}\\
$$
I used this to open the following expectation:
$$
E[\bar{y}^{3}- \mu^{3}] = E[(\bar{y}-\mu)^{3}-3\bar{y}^{2}\mu+3\bar{y}\mu^{2}] = 
$$
$$
 E[(\bar{y}-\mu)^{3}] + 3\mu E[\bar{y}^{2} - \bar{y}\mu] 
$$
$$
 E[(\bar{y}-\mu)^{3}] + 3\mu [E[\bar{y}^{2}] - \mu E[\bar{y}]] 
$$
However, I don't know how I can continue from here once $\bar{y} = \frac{1}{N} \sum y_{i}$ I tried to open this definition but with little success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $E[\bar{y}] = \mu$ and $V[\bar{y}] = E[\bar{y}^2] - \mu^2 =  \sigma^2/n$.
Further
$$
(\bar{y} - \mu)^3= \bar{y}^3 - \mu^3 + 3 \mu^2 \bar{y} - 3 \mu \bar{y}^2
$$
and so from this we can see that
$$
\bar{y}^3 - \mu^3 = (\bar{y} - \mu)^3 - 3 \mu^2\bar{y} + 3 \mu \bar{y}^2
$$
and therefore
\begin{align*}
E[\bar{y}^3] - \mu^3 
&= E[(\bar{y} - \mu)^3] - 3 \mu^2 E[\bar{y}] + 3 \mu E[\bar{y}^2] \\
&= E[(\bar{y} - \mu)^3] - 3 \mu^3 + 3 \mu (\sigma^2/n + \mu^2) \\
&= E[(\bar{y} - \mu)^3] + 3 \sigma^2\mu/n
\end{align*}

Now,
$$
E[(\bar{y} - \mu)^3]=
E \left [ \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (y_i -\mu)\right)^3  \right ]=
\frac{1}{n^3} \left[\sum_i E(y_i -\mu)^3\  \right ]
=\frac{1}{n^2} E(y -\mu)^3
$$
where the last two equalities hold by independence and identical distribution, respectively.